# how to show width and height of image in react native

Tags: react-native

how Can I show width and height of an image , I use this syntax :

```
const width = Image.getSize(imag, (width, height)=>JSON.stringify(width));
```

now if I `alert({width})`  it shows object Object but if I put alert within getSize function it display the value like this :

```
Image.getSize(imag, (width, height)=>{alert(JSON.stringify(width))});
```

I want to store the value in a variable like in my first example and then get access to it , this is a function component , no setState, could you please help

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the variable in the `success` callback.

```
let width = null;

Image.getSize(image, (imageWidth) => {
  width = imageWidth;
  alert("Width", width);
});
```

The documentation states:

> This method can fail if the image cannot be found, or fails to download.

You could also try using [`resolveAssetSource`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resolveassetsource)

```
const { width } = Image.resolveAssetSource(image);
alert(width);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Dan but alert now shows null  I made :    let width = null;
   Image.getSize(imag, (imageWidth) => {
        width = imageWidth;
      });
     alert(width);

Comment: @findAffs I've updated the answer. Also, what is the value of `image`?

Comment: Try `const { width } = Image.resolveAssetSource({ uri: 'https://i.imgur.com/ws55P6a.jpg' });`

Comment: this last example you gave me it alerts 'undifened'  and then I 've added {} to width it alerts [object Ojbect] by the way I am testing android emulator , IMAC , "react-native": "0.57.7"